# language translation to Spanish?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am English, and living in Spain where I am starting to work with kids teaching Lego robotics with an established group of eager learners. I would also like to move them onto ROS. I am more than happy to help with translating your docs into Spanish (its also good for me!), but is there a driver to do this already?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259008/language-translation-to-spanish?/) by [chris2far](https://answers.ros.org/users/29993/chris2far/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the translation for spanish language is already there :)

just visit the http://wiki.ros.org/es

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris2far](https://answers.ros.org/users/29993/chris2far/) on 2017-04-11**:
thanks...I noticed in the end :-)